# jquery TableSorter stops working if I add 2014-03-31 kind of date string in title filed

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

jquery TableSorter stops working if I add 2014-03-31 kind of date string in Name Column, which is non-date column? Will be grateful for any guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tablesorter attempts to detect the type of data contained in a column.

When the first cell in the column contains `2014-03-31 Philip Aaron Wong`, it appears to contain numbers, so the parser gets set to `digit`.

To fix this, set the class name of the header cell to "sorter-text" ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/7415/)):

```
<th class="sorter-text">First Name</th>
```

In the future, try the `debug` option, it will report what parsers are being set.